# Map of Avro objects serialization with Kryo - Spark

Tags: serialization, apache-spark, avro, kryo

I have a question about specific avro serialization with kryo. Sorry if this question seems redundant but I didn't find a simple answer.

I've configured Spark to run with Kryo and it works well : Avro generated classes are well serialized using a custom KryoRegistrator class. I use `twitter.chill-avro` package too.

```
class AvroClassRegistrator extends KryoRegistrator {
  override def registerClasses(kryo: Kryo) {
    kryo.register(classOf[MyAvroClass], AvroSerializer.SpecificRecordSerializer[MyAvroClass])
}
```

Nevertheless, when I try to serialize a `Map[String, MyAvroClass]`, the only way to make the serialization work is to extends `MyAvroClass` with `java.io.Serializable`.

Could somebody explain me what really happens, and tell me how to register this  `Map[..., AvroClass]` with kryo ?

Thank you

Comment: Well, in fact this does not works too, the serialized class is full of null attributes.